# How do I git checkout a specific version of the Android support libraries?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-source

I git cloned the Android support libraries repository:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/
```

Now let's say I want to checkout version 26.1.0. How can I do that ? There doesn't seem to be any tag or branch matching.

Comment: Do you want study the code of support library or use it in your project?

Comment: Just study the code. I know it comes as a zip in the Sdk directory somewhere but I would like the git history.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the branches for the support framework that you mentioned. It's easier to browse on Github.
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/branches/all

Comment: FYI:  You can see all the branches on any locally checked out git repository by executing the command:  git branch -av

Comment: And you can see the tags with "git tag -l".  Though it seems google is not labelling things as 23.2.1 and so forth.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, I want to know what tag exactly is 23.2.1 as described in http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code on [github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support). As I saw last commit on the github was 3 hours ago but on the googlesource same commit was merged one hour later. If clone code from googlesource  there is only one branch master. Although there are a lot of TAGs last is `android-support-lib-19.1.0`. I think that last changes don't available for everyone. Google developers publish code diff later. There are last code [diff](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23/changes.html) from 
Chris Banes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that through Android Studio itself:

1. Right click on your **app** module. Go to **Module Settings**.
2. Select **Dependencies** tab on the right end.
3. Click on the **+** icon at bottom and select **Library dependency**.
4. Search for the specific version you need for a support library.

Comment: How does that give me the git commit of version 26.1.0 ?

Comment: You won't have to pull the library through git. It'll be directly added to your project.

Comment: I actually want to get the source code with history.